# Initialize a php script then stop to do another job

Tags: process, php

I'm looking for a method to initialize a php script (`script.php`) from a php script (`main.php`) then the `main.php` quickly skip the running process of `script.php` to continue for its main job.

I know it is a confusing question and a little difficult to understand what i want to ask. Basically i have `main.php` file:

```
 <?php
 include('script.php');


//do the main job
?>
```

But the `script.php` script takes long time to run, so i want after the `include('script.php'` command is initialized, the `main.php` script will quickly ignore this step and continue to proceed to its main job, regardless of whether `script.php` has finished or not.

Is there any way to achieve such thing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is single threaded (well, not entirely, but thats out of scope).

If you want to spawn a seperate process, you will have to use PHP cli (executable php) by using ie. `exec()`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Ofcourse this does mean you need to have exec enabled in the php configuration.

So instead of the include, use `exec('/usr/bin/php script.php  > /dev/null 2>&1 &');`

Ofcourse the path of `/usr/bin/php` should point to the php executable on the filessystem.

The `&` makes the process go in the background, causing the main script to continue.

The `> /dev/null` bit causes the output to go into nothingness.
The `2>&1` it causes errors to also go into nothingness (so be sure to find another way to log)

Both are neccesary, since you have no way to catch output once you toss the script into the background.

Also read the "see also" bit of http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for other options like passthru, system etc. What you need to use depends on what you need exactly..

Comment: Thank Damien. Very nice and detail explanation :). I have made it work now :)